# Converting raw images with Electron js

Tags: image-processing, electron

I'd like to build an Electron app that batch converts raw (CR2 in specific) images to JPG and than resizes them. But all the image processing libraries I've seen use some external image processing library such as imagemagick. Is there a way to ship these libraries along the Electron app, or work around them?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking for, but you can call external libraries with

```
var remote = require('remote');
var exec = remote.require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = "start imagemagick.exe -arguments"

exec(cmd, function(err,stdout, stderr){
   //callback code
});
```

Edit: Also this exists. https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick

install alongside with `npm install imagemagick`

Comment: Well, that means that the user would have to have imagemagick installed on his machine. I think that the point of the question (I may be wrong) is to figure out how to process images in an electron app avoiding the installation of any external libs on the user's computer.

Comment: Yea, it would be weird for the user to have to install two softwares to get something to work.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac there's a command-line program called `sips` which basically exposes the same libraries that Aperture and Photos use.

https://coderwall.com/p/nhp7mq/convert-raw-photos-to-jpg-in-the-mac-os-terminal

e.g.

`for i in *.CR2; do sips -s format jpeg $i --out "${i%.*}.jpg"; done`

Obviously (a) this is Mac only and Apple has marked it as "deprecated" in its developer documentation and (b) it only supports whatever cameras are supported in the OS version you're using (so users of older Macs won't have support for the latest proprietary files).